# Exporting all columns(including hidden) in an Ag grid react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I want to be able to export my AG grid to CSV so that it includes the hidden columns in the export. When I right click on the grid to export it only exports the visible columns (not the hidden ones). I know there is an API call I can make which will allow me to export all columns, but is there a way of exporting all by using the built in export functionality (right click).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your `defaultExportParams` which are the params used for the export when exporting via right click. Set the property `allColumns` to `true` in these params, and it should export all columns, including hidden columns.

See [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/export/) for the list of available properties for `defaultExportParams`.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/dW5Lql9KA5FlMmK6)